# Using articles for mathematical objects

Tags: articles, definite-articles

I am writing a paper and don't know whether I need to use "the", or no article in the following cases.

1) I write "Let M be a matrix such as...".  Then I need to refer to this matrix further in the text. Which one is correct:

- Consider the element M(i,j) of the matrix M
- Consider the element M(i,j) of matrix M
- Consider element M(i,j) of the matrix M
- Consider element M(i,j) of matrix M

2) Again, I define an algorithm, and name it "algorithm A". Which one is correct:

- Applying the algorithm A, one gets...
- Applying algorithm A, one gets...

3) Finally, I need to refer to an algorithm from another paper. This paper contains several algorithms, none of them has a unique name, but from the text it’s clear which of the algorithms is meant. Which one is correct:

- This procedure is based on the algorithm from [3]
- This procedure is based on algorithm from [3]

Comment: It has nothing to do with math. Just follow the English grammar rules for the definite article. Good Luck.

Comment: #1 is unclear without context. Both are grammatical. Which is correct depends on your intent. #2 no article. #3 use the article.

Answer (score 0):

The custom in mathematical writing is that once an item has been named, you don't use the article.

> Consider element *M(i,j)* of the matrix *M*

would be appropriate in the beginning, where you're starting to talk about the matrix *M*.

After you've outlined or described Algorithm A, then you can talk about it without *an* or *the*.

Look at some published articles in math or computer science and then follow the rule, *When in Rome, do as the Romans do.*